# Declare Two Dimensional Double Array Inside Structure

Tags: c#

How can I declare a two dimensional double array inside the structure?

```
public struct PROBABILTY_SETUP
{
    double[,] probablity[2,9613];
}
```

The above code NOT WORKING...

Comment: The question needs a little more info what you are trying to do. Right now it is impossible to know the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct PROBABILTY_SETUP
    {
        double[,] probablity;

        public PROBABILTY_SETUP(double [,] probability)
        {
            this.probablity = probability;
        }
    }
```

You'll have to call the constructor with the array you require:

`PROBABILITY_SETUP mySetup = new PROBABILITY_SETUP(new double[2, 9613]);`

Comment: It says cannot have instance field initializers in structs

Comment: Structs are value types and cannot have defaults assigned to them.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're in a `struct`, you'd have to make it `static`, as you can't have an initializer for a non-static `struct` member (another option is use a constructor however).

If it was a `class` however, the below would work without the `static` keyword.

Try this:

```
public struct PROBABILITY_SETUP
{
    static double[,] probablity = new double[2, 9613];
}
```

**If you require more than one however, consider using a `constructor`**

Comment: If you make it static, you can only have one.

Comment: @SLC True, I best mention that in my answer. If OP wants more than one, a constructor would be the way to go.